# Save a list of resized pictures by their original name

Tags: python

I have a list of pictures i have resized in python. Is there any ways that i can save this resized pictures in a new folder by the original name? I have tried, but now they are renamed to "filename1, filename2...."

```
from PIL import Image
import glob 
from natsort import natsorted 

new_width = 300 
new_height = 300

images = [] 
resized = [] 



for filename in natsorted(glob.glob('Pictures/*.jpg')):
    print(filename) 

    img = Image.open(filename) 

    images.append(img)

for image in images: 

    image=image.resize((new_height,new_width)) 

    resized.append(image)  



for(i,new) in enumerate(resized):

    new.save('{}{}{}'.format('resize/filename', i + 1, '.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the filenames somewhere. I save them in a list of tuples `(filename, resized_image)`.
This code example does what you want:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob 
from natsort import natsorted 

new_width = 300 
new_height = 300

resized = [] 

for filename in natsorted(glob.glob('Pictures/*.jpg')):
    print(filename) 

    img = Image.open(filename) 
    img_resized = img.resize((new_height, new_width)) 

    resized.append((filename, img_resized))  

for (filename, new) in resized:

    new.save(filename)
```